# How to extract href and src result from a plain text returned from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have to use a widget which is not written good at all. So it returns a function with some bad codes using document.write and I do not want to insert it that into my page. Here is what is returned:

```
if (position == 'Right') {
  document.write('<A HREF="xxxxxx/xxxx/xxx-   www.xxxx.com/xxxx/default/empty.gif/1?x" target="_top"><IMG    SRC="https://cdn.oas-c17.adnxs.com/RealMedia/ads/Creatives/default/empty.gif/0" WIDTH=1 HEIGHT=1 ALT="" BORDER=0 BORDER="0"></A>');
}
```

Instead I use ajax call to get everything in plain text and all I need is just the result of href and src of the above text. So I need to parse the text and get:

```
https://xxxx-www.xxxx.com/xxx/home/1735871518/Right/default/empty.gif/1?x
```

and

```
https://cdn.oas-c17.adnxs.com/RealMedia/ads/Creatives/default/empty.gif/0
```

Here is my call to get the plain text:

```
function getTodaysAd() {
  $.ajax({
    url : "https:xxxxxxxxxx",
    dataType : 'text',
    cache : false,
    success : function(data) {
      alert();
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(textStatus);
    }
  });
}
```

Since I usually get everything back in JSON I am having a hard time parsing this plain text. Is it doable via regular expression?

Comment: HTML is *not* a regular language.  Don't try using regular expressions to parse HTML.

Comment: @Amy thanks amy for answering. what if I replace the html tags with nothing. Since I just need the src and href which are basically two plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can extract the `<a>` tag out of the response with this regex:

```
var markup = data.match(/document.write\s?\('([^']*)'/i);
// searches for "document.write (' [...] '"
```

Your `markup[1]` variable should contain all of the markup that was going to be written by the function, something like this:

```
<A     HREF="xxxxxx/ads/click_lx.ads/stage6-   www.xxxx.com/xxxx/default/empty.gif/1?x" target="_top"><IMG    SRC="https://cdn.oas-c17.adnxs.com/RealMedia/ads/Creatives/default/empty.gif/0"     WIDTH=1 HEIGHT=1 ALT="" BORDER=0 BORDER="0"></A>
```

Next, you can use jQuery to turn this into an HTML node, like so:

```
var a = $(markup[1]);
```

Now, you'll have an `<a>` tag that you can parse like any other element on your page. You can retrieve the `href` and `src` like so:

```
var href = a.attr('href');
var src = a.find('img').attr('src');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try it right a way and will let you know how it works

Answer (score 1):

If your string always has the format you gave you can do the following:

```
var nonFormattedCode = '<A     HREF="xxxxxx/xxxx/xxx-   www.xxxx.com/xxxx/default/empty.gif/1?x" target="_top"><IMG    SRC="https://cdn.oas-c17.adnxs.com/RealMedia/ads/Creatives/default/empty.gif/0"     WIDTH=1 HEIGHT=1 ALT="" BORDER=0 BORDER="0"></A>';

var href = nonFormattedCode.replace(/\s+/g,'').match(/HREF\=\"(.*)"target/)[1];
var src = nonFormattedCode.replace(/\s+/g,'').match(/SRC\=\"(.*)"WIDTH/)[1];
```

It's ugly, but it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

As long as it's plain text and what you're parsing is that exactly in that format, you certainly can.

```
/*...*/
success: function(data) {
    var href = data.match(/HREF="(.*?)"/)[1]; // https://xxxx-www.xxxx.com/xxx/home/1735871518/Right/default/empty.gif/1?x
    var src = data.match(/SRC="(.*?)"/)[1]; // https://cdn.oas-c17.adnxs.com/RealMedia/ads/Creatives/default/empty.gif/0
}
/*...*/
```

If you need the full string, including the `HREF=` part, just replace the `[1]`s with 0s. `String.match()` returns an array consisting of the full match and then each matched group, and `"(.*?)"` searches for literally everything starting after a quotation mark, and ending at the next one.

So `data.match(/HREF="(.*?)"/)` returns:

```
['HREF="http://www.url.com"', 'http://www.url.com']
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you appear to be using jQuery, why bother with Regular Expressions at all? You could just create a virtual element from the string, like so:

```
var $element = $('<A HREF="xxxxxx/xxxx/xxx-   www.xxxx.com/xxxx/default/empty.gif/1?x" target="_top"><IMG    SRC="https://cdn.oas-c17.adnxs.com/RealMedia/ads/Creatives/default/empty.gif/0" WIDTH=1 HEIGHT=1 ALT="" BORDER=0 BORDER="0"></A>');
```

Then you could grab whatever attributes you want like you typically would with an element on the page:

```
var href = $element.attr('href');
var src  = $element.children('img').first().attr('src');
```

A much safer approach, IMHO, since it's not depending on the string to be formatted in a very specific way to get a clean match from a regex.

Comment: Thanks a  lot for the answer :)

Comment: Glad to help! :-)